# Can't get search function to list out serach result

Tags: android

This is my database where I store all my information to be display on the
   list.

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "imagedb";
private static final String TAG = "DataBaseHandler";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String KEY_SEARCH = "searchData";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"+  
KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_SEARCH + " TEXT,"
            +" UNIQUE (" + KEY_NAME + "));" + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    Log.w(TAG, CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

public// Adding new contact
long addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String searchValue = contact._name + " ";
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact._name); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, contact._price); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_IMAGE, contact._image); // Contact Phone
    values.put(KEY_SEARCH, searchValue); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    return db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);

}



// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM contacts ORDER BY name";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setPrice(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setImage(cursor.getBlob(4));
            contact.setSearch(cursor.getString(3));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // close inserting data from database
    db.close();
    // return contact list
    return contactList;

}


public Cursor searchCustomer(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    String query = " SELECT id as _id," + KEY_NAME + "," + KEY_PRICE +
            " from " + TABLE_CONTACTS +
            " where " +  KEY_SEARCH + " LIKE '" + inputText + "';";
    Log.w(TAG, query);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}
// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

This is my search function where when I search for the words, the list view
   supposed to show the search result that matches the words. However, the list
   view unable to display the search result. Is it due to the data isn't get 
   from the database?

```
public class Search extends Activity implements   
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    SearchView.OnCloseListener{
private ListView mListView;
private SearchView searchView;
DataBaseHandler db;

private TextView nameText;
private TextView priceText;
private SimpleAdapter customers;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    db = new DataBaseHandler(this);

}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    showResults(newText + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    showResults(query + "*");
    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {
    showResults("");
    return false;
}

private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = db.searchCustomer((query != null ? query.toString() : 
"@@@@"));

    if (cursor == null) {
        //
    } else {
        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] {
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_NAME,
                DataBaseHandler.KEY_PRICE};

        // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the 
  columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] {     R.id.txtTitle,
                R.id.txtPrice};
        System.out.println("hello1");
        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them 
  to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter customers = new 
  SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(customers);
        System.out.println("hell1");
        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
  position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in
  the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) 
  mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                System.out.println("hel1");
                // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.
                String name = 
  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
                String price = 
  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price"));
                System.out.println("hello2");

                //Get References to the TextViews
                nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitles);
                priceText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrices);
                System.out.println("hello3");
                // Update the parent class's TextView
                nameText.setText(name);
                priceText.setText(price);
                System.out.println("hello4");
                searchView.setQuery("", true);
            }
        });

    }
   }

  }
```

Comment: Add logs. Every place you can. Before calling a function, after entering one, before making a db call, after returning from one, etc etc to check what really is happening. Then check what output you get from the db calls. If that is good, then the problem is with displaying the content. Otherwise, relook your db calls.

Comment: call DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor and see if your Cursor is empty or not